# tunnel in macOS ssh using netcat

Tags: macos, ssh, tunnel

I am trying to find the alternative command for this ubuntu ssh tunnel script. Unfortunately, there is no nc.traditional on Mac as far as I know and looked. What could be the alternative for this command?

```
ssh -fN -L 2222:layout.uni.edu:22 user@transit.uni.edu

# Continuous chained tunnel between your laptop and rmworkstation
while true
do
   nc.traditional -p 2223 -c "ssh -p 2222 user@localhost nc rmworkstation 22"
done
```

Comment: Can you explain what this command does?

Comment: I think it does port forwarding to an ssh tunnel. I am really not sure since the person who made this script is unreachable...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand it correctly, but you might be able to get the same effect with something like:

```
ssh -J user@transit.uni.edu -L 2223:rmworkstation:22 user@layout.uni.edu
```

What it does: ssh to transit.uni.edu, then tunnel another ssh connection across that to layout.uni.edu, and open a TCP tunnel across *that* from localhost:2223 to rmworkstation:22.

The ProxyJump (`-J`) option was introduced in OpenSSH v7.3, so if you don't have that on either the client mac or transit.uni.edu, you'll need to do a more manual version, like this:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@transit.uni.edu" -L 2223:rmworkstation:22 user@layout.uni.edu
```